# How to filter a Django model based on requirement from another model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'd like to retrieve all my contacts from my `Contact` model excluding those listed on my `DoNotContact` model. Is the following the most efficient way to do that: `contacts = Contact.objects.filter(dont_contact=False)` Wondering if this is going to take long to process, is there a more efficient way?

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    audience = models.ForeignKey(Audience, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def dont_contact(self):
        try:
            get_object_or_404(DoNotContact, email=self.email)
            return True
        except:
            return False


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

class DoNotContact(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=12)


#views.py
def send_email(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        contacts = Contact.objects.filter(dont_contact=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kwargs used model queryset filter methods are resolved into database columns. `dont_contact` here is a method and doesn't exist as a column in `Contact` model so calling `Contact.objects.filter(dont_contact=False)` will raise a `FieldError`.

For current implementation of your models you can do following

```
dont_contacts = DoNotContact.objects.values('email')
contacts = Contact.objects.exclude(email__in=dont_contacts)
```

A better solution with higher performance is to remove `DoNotContact` and add a `BooleanField` to `Contact` which handles your requirement.

Comment: For certain reasons related to my app, I  cannot have a boolean field related to contacting in `Contact`. How low performance will my current implement, with your recommended adjustments be?

Comment: In my opinion, it wouldn't convert to a bottleneck. In this case, two queries are performed compared to one if we use `BooleanField`.

Comment: I didn't understand what you meant. Do you mean if I keep both models `DoNotContact` and `Contact` it's ok, and shouldn't have a big effect on performance?

Comment: Yes! There wouldn't be considerable performance chnage if you keep both models.